# Making varchar(500) datacolumn unique

Tags: sql-server, unique-key

I have a requirement to make a column of varchar(500) unique.
Putting unique constraint would not work as it crosses the size limit of unique.
Then, what would be the best strategy to make column unique?

Comment: Are you stuck with the database structure or can you alter it?

Comment: Yes I can alter the structure.

Comment: What is the size limitation on unique indexes?

Comment: By 500 I mean size larger than that, like if we put unique index on varchar(1000) field then it would give following warning: "Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'UQ__tmp__43D2EAF819DFD96B' has maximum length of 1000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail."

Comment: Size limit is 900 bytes for the key of an index. So varchar(900) or nvarchar(450). How many rows do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another field with the HASH of that `varchar(500)`, and put a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the hash field: `HASHBYTES('md5', MyLongVarcharField)`

This will cause poor performance but if you have a `varchar(500)` where you need to enforce uniqueness I'm assuming performance isn't on the forefront of your considerations anyways.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the chance of having two strings output the same 128 bit hash value is `1 in 340,282,366,920,938,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000`.  It's unlikely but not categorically **impossible** that you could have a collision.

If you are still concerned you can use `SHA` or `SHA1` algorithms which are 160 bits.

Comment: Won't hash collisions be a real issue with this solution, assuming there are enough rows of data?  It would only be in really rare circumstances.

Comment: Chances of a hash collision with md5 are 1/2^128.  It's more likely the OP will be struck by lightning at the same time that a meteor hits him.

Comment: 2^28 is 268,435,456 which is big, but not that big in certain systems.  I agree it's not a deal breaker, but it's something to consider.

Comment: @MatthewVines - I mistyped, its 2^128 not 28. :)

Comment: @JNK can you please provide some info or link on why to create HASH field and how it actually hits the performance?

Comment: @DarshanJoshi - **No.**  For performance you will need to test, but it will negatively impact it since you are running a function against a long string for each row.  For a reference, this is a very common technique.  I'm not going to give you a citation on how a `WHERE` clause works either, but if you don't trust me you can check MSDN.

Comment: One could use SHA1 to reduce collisions, both are subject to the birthday paradox anyway http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DML trigger on INSERT and UPDATE.  This gets around having to use a hash.  I chose an AFTER trigger for simplicity, but this can be easily done with an INSTEAD OF trigger as well.

```
create trigger dml_EnforceUniqueVal
on dbo.UniqueBigColumn
after insert, update
as  
    declare @CountOfRepeats int
    select @CountOfRepeats = COUNT(*)
    from UniqueBigColumn
    where somestring in
    (
        select somestring
        from inserted
    )

    if @CountOfRepeats > 1
        rollback
go
```